# For given binary string find maximum sub-string with equal number of ones and zeroes

Tags: arrays, string

I'm trying to solve this problem, let's say we have given string of length up to 100000 which consists only 0 and 1, now for this string we want to check which is the longest substring that contains equal number of zeroes and ones.

**Example**

Let's say we have string "1010110", the biggest substring that can be found in this string is with size 6 and that is the substring which is starting on position 1(if the string is zero-indexed), actually that is the string "010110".

**What i tried**

I tried to solve this with two nested loops such that the first one (i) goes from 0 to n-1, where n is length of the string and the second one(j) goes from i to n, I'm creating array of integers and instead of 0 I'm keeping -1, and now i just check if the sum of the elements from i to j is 0 if it is zero then we compare the size of that substring to the final result

Comment: What have you tried so far? How did or didn't that work? Please take some time to [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I'm sorry, I just updated my question. I hope now it's more clear.